# RadioButton Layout

Tags: android

I am trying to make a RadioGroup with several RadioButtons. The first RadioButton is defined in an xml-File:

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonFirst"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:gravity="center" />


    </RadioGroup>
```

The rest can only be added during runtime because the number of needed RadioButtons can vary.

```
RadioButton rbNext = new RadioButton(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsRb = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        paramsRb.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, rbFirst.getId());
        paramsRb.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        paramsRb.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, ivNext.getId());
        paramsRb.setMargins(0, 0, 20, 0);

        rbNext.setLayoutParams(paramsRb);
        rbNext.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        rbNext.setId(i*10+1);
```

Creating and adding the RadioButtons works perfectly but how can I distribute the RadioButtons over the whole width of the RadioGroup?

Comment: you have try using LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT instead of LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT

Comment: that's right, you should use `FILL_PARENT` for the **`radioGroup1`**'s width.

Comment: ohh I wrote width but I ment height...

Answer (score 0):

Get your RadioGroup by Id and add your Buttons as a childs.

```
(RadioGroup) radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findByViewId(radioGroup1);
radioGroup.addView(yourRadioButton);
```